# BlackBerry: Screen not scrolling on touch

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-storm, blackberry-torch

I am building a BlackBerry Java application and I want my screen to scroll when I drag my finger on touch. This behavior works perfectly on other screens where I am implementing a ListField. However, on the screen where I am having an issue, I am subclassing FullScreen and simply adding a series of BitmapFields (with Field.NON_FOCUSABLE style) and RichTextFields (with Field.FOCUSABLE style) to the screen's main VerticalFieldManager. I have set the screen style to Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL and scrolling works fine when using the navigation pad. It is only on touch events that the scrolling does not work.

Any ideas on how to correct this? Thanks.

Comment: When you say it "works perfectly on other screens", do you mean your navigation works perfectly on non-touch devices?

Comment: I mean on the other screens within the application, I've implemented a ListField and on those screens I am able to scroll on touch devices.

Answer (score 0):

once check Focusble or  nonfocusble  in the textfield